# Sorting not working on magento246p1 (Facing error : We can't find products matching the selection)

Tags: magento2, sorting, magento2.4.6

using magento 2.4.6

getting issue in plp custom sort
[image]
Elasticsearch is working fine
and also run indexer:reindex command

```
<?php
namespace Tekglide\CategorySortBy\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        if ($currentOrder == "latest") {
            $dir = $subject->getCurrentDirection();
            $collection->getSelect()->order('created_at ' . $dir);
        }
        return $proceed($collection);
    }
}
```

This is the query on getselect()

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0)
AS `rating_summary` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1' LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product')) ORDER BY `created_at` asc;
```